At what point are shopware rules applied to the cart?
The Shopware v6.5 CartRuleLoader class contains the load method which contains this piece of code $rules = $this->loadRules($context->getContext()).
After the rules are gotten, the $ruleIds are added to Shopware $context.
My question now is: at what point are the retrieved $rules applied to the cart or used to manipulate the cart?
